# Association analysis returns 0 useful rules

Tags: r, association-rules

Since new to association rules need help for identifying the most frequent 
extra service ordered together with the products. And to derive the 
association rules, I have used `arules` R package on past data.

I have collected and shaped the dataset as like
you can download sample dataset from link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/4g5sqag9afsttmo/finaldf2.csv).

When I tried it with the following set of R codes, it can't calculate the 
association rules between product and services. But it calculates the rules between all 
services.

Can any one guide me why I am getting set of 0 rules for calculation of association rules of product. Am I doing something wrong to calculate the associations. Or 
My dataset should be different.

Here are the R codes generated for `arules`:

```
# Loading the library
library(arules)    

# Loading the dataset 
product.transaction.set <- read.csv("finaldf2.csv")    

# calculating the association with apriori algo
rules <- apriori(product.transaction.set, parameter = list(support = 0.4,conf = 0.6,target = "rules"))

## 1 - for product
# Deriving the association rules for productname
rules.sub.product <- subset(rules, subset = lhs %pin% "LD") # output -> set of 0 rules     

# for print the calculated association rules
inspect(rules.sub.product) 

## 2- for add on services ()
# Deriving the association rules for add on services
rules.sub.services <- subset(rules, subset = lhs %pin% "AO1") # output -> set of 1 rules 

# for print the calculated association rules
inspect(rules.sub.services)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the problem related to value of the support and confidence. Based on the problem and dataset information we can vary them and generate the association rules. In my case I got it by providing the support=0.1 and confident =0.4